# Geocoding API in CartoDB

Tags: carto, geocoding

I had set up my local cartodb instance in server. I had searched specifically for geocoding API in cartodb, but couldnot find any. I would like to know is there any API for geocoding in cartodb?

Answer (score 2):

Right now there's not a public Geocoding API offered by CartoDB, but it's something in the roadmap.

I'll try to update this answer as soon as there are news on this matter.

Comment: Is there any update on this?

Comment: Not yet, but soon. ;-)